# Proof that if $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ is continuous, then $\{ x \mid \phi(x) \geq \alpha \}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing, self-learning

Recently, having realized I did not properly internalize it (shame on me!), I went back to the definition of continuity in metric spaces and I found a proposition for which I was looking for a proof.

Here there is the result and my "proof" (in the hope to get rid of the quotation marks).

*[In general, I use $N_{\varepsilon, X} (x)$ to denote an open $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $x \in X$.]*

> **Proposition:** Let $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ be a continuous function, with $X$ an arbitrary metric space. Then, the set $\{ x \mid \phi(x) \geq \alpha \}$ is closed.
>
> *Attempted proof:*
> Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary real number. We establish the result by showing that $\{ x \mid \phi(x) < \alpha \}$ is an open set in $X$. Notice that for every $x \in X$, if $\phi (x) < \alpha$, then there is a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that there is an open neighbourhood $N_{\varepsilon, \mathbb{R}} (\phi (x)) < \alpha$. Let $z \in X$ be arbitrary and such that $\phi (z) < \alpha$. Hence, by the  definition of continuity and the fact that $\phi$ is continuous, there is a $\delta (z, \varepsilon) > 0$ such that
>
> $$N_{\delta, X} (z) \subseteq \phi^{-1} ( N_{\varepsilon, \mathbb{R}} ( \phi (z)). $$
>
> Hence, being $z \in X$ arbitrary, the proposition follows.

*Is this proof correct?*

As always, any feedback is more than welcome.
Thank you for your time.

---

**Edit:**
I know it is possible to proceed, as hinted by air in a comment below, through the fact that the if a function is continuous, then the preimage of a closed set is closed. However, I find this solution a bit too *topological*, in the sense that I really would like to know about this $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof, which – to me – has a stronger metric flavour.

Comment: It seems that some words are missing in the sentence "Notice that for every $x\in X$,..."

Comment: I find your proof a bit hard to follow and I suspect there are multiple typos, e.g. in the indexing of your neighborhoods. Anyway, the basic idea for proving this is to observe that 1) $[\alpha,\infty) \subset \mathbb R$ is a closed subset and 2) that the pre-image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed again.

Comment: Thanks! I think I corrected all the typos. Indeed, that was my line of reasoning, but still I was interested in both the soundness of the proof, and the way of writing it. *Is it OK now?*

Comment: Look right before you say the words "Let $z \in X$".  You invoked $z$ right before you declared it.

Comment: @Kolmin One more typo: "There is an open neighbourhood $N_{\varepsilon, X} (\phi (x))$", it should be $\mathbb R$ in the index again. Also I feel like this sentence is not finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the amazing amount of typos you found (shame on me!). I also changed the text as it was originally in my handwritten proof, and I had forgot to write down. Now, this should make sense (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: You are assuming that $X$ is a metric space (otherwise $N_{\delta,X}(z)$ would make no sense). But this assumption is not necessary. That is why a topological proof is better than an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof $-$ it is more general.

Comment: @TonyK: I see, but the point of looking for a $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof really lies in my first comment to user46944 answer.

Comment: But then you must state this assumption (that $X$ is a metric space) as a condition of your Proposition, otherwise your proof is invalid.

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks for this feedback. I actually edited the answer to take into account this as well. However, I am not really sure I see it. Do you mean it to exclude that $X$ is an arbitrary topological space? (But then the all $\varepsilon - \delta$ procedure would not make much sense).

Comment: Your Proposition is true for any topological space $X$. But your proof of it is only valid if $X$ is a metric space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now the proof is basically correct (when we are working in metric spaces)! Some remarks:

As Umberto P. also noted in his answer in the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456524/proof-based-on-convergence-arguments-that-if-phi-in-mathbbrx-is-continu) you asked, I am not fond of the notation "$N_{\varepsilon, \mathbb{R}} (\phi (x)) < \alpha$". In fact in the other thread you write "$\phi(Y) \le \alpha$" for a set $Y$, which is still a bit more appropriate than what you write here (though still false).

You should write instead: There is a neighborhood $N_{\varepsilon, \mathbb{R}} (\phi (x))$ such that or all $y \in N_{\varepsilon, \mathbb{R}} (\phi (x))$ it holds that $y < \alpha$.

Also towards the end, your argument is correct but I usually like to be a bit more explicit (at least until you get more comfortable with the material). For example I would write: By the continuity of $\phi$ there exists $\delta:=\delta (z, \varepsilon) > 0$ such that $|\phi(x)-\phi(z)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in N_{\delta, X}(z)$. This implies that for $x \in N_{\delta, X}(z)$ it holds that $\phi(x) \in N_{\varepsilon, \mathbb{R}} (\phi (z))$. Therefore we finally have that:

$$N_{\delta, X} (z) \subseteq \phi^{-1} ( N_{\varepsilon, \mathbb{R}} ( \phi (z)) \subseteq \{ x \mid \phi(x) < \alpha \}$$

This finishes our proof. (Note the final inclusion; you had already shown it but I still feel it is critical to the argument and should be repeated at this point.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your super-detailed answer (and also for the amount of time spent finding all my bad typos)! About the notation you mention in the second paragraph, it is quite literally borrowed from the book I am reading (see the last comment to Umberto P.'s answer on the other question), that's why I felt I could apply it, but I see the point of why it is tricky (indeed, I did not define $\phi$ as a – possibly – set function, hence I could not really use it as I did).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you need an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof when we aren't trying to prove continuity.  We are just trying to prove $\{x \mid \phi(x) \geq a \}$ is closed if $\phi$ is continuous.

It suffices to show the complement is open.  But since $\{x \mid \phi(x) \geq a \} = \phi^{-1}( [a, \infty) )$, and $f^{-1}(B^{c}) = (f^{-1}(B))^{c}$ for every function $f$ and every set $B$ in the codomain of $f$, we have:

$[a,\infty)^{c} = (-\infty, a)$ which is open.  Since $\phi$ is continuous, $\phi^{-1}( (-\infty, a))$ is open.  But $\phi^{-1}( (-\infty, a)) = \phi^{-1}( [a, \infty)^{c}) = (\phi^{-1}([a, \infty))^{c}$.

Thus, $(\phi^{-1}([a, \infty))^{c}$ is open, and so its complement, $\phi^{-1}([a,\infty))$ is closed. But $\phi^{-1}([a,\infty))$ is just another notation for $\{x \mid \phi(x) \geq a \}$, so our set is closed, as desired.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer! The point is that in the book I am self-studying, continuity is defined, then there is this proposition, and then – only after – there is the standard characterization in terms of preimages of open/closed sets. Considering I think I have some overall problems in grasping how an $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof proceeds, I really wanted to get the result in this way (also because, being self-thaught I want to be sure I properly grasp concepts). Hence, that's why I am so interested in this specific proof I came up with, even if this looks just cumbersome.

Comment: Hence, after all, if I may ask you, is the proof actually correct? :-)

Comment: @Kolmin The wording of the proof bothers me a little.  For example, you say "Notice that for every $x \in X$, if $\phi(x) < a$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an open neighborhood $N_{\epsilon, X} (\phi(x))$."  And then you stop there.  How is this neighborhood defined?  What purpose does this neighborhood serve?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this feedback. I actually changed the sentence (going back to the original handwritten proof I had) in such a way that should make sense.