# Proof based on convergence arguments that, if $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ is continuous, then $\{ x \ | \ \phi (x) \leq \alpha \}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Recently, I posted a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455348/proof-that-if-phi-in-mathbbrx-is-continuous-then-x-phix-g) of the proposition that, given a continuous function $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$, the set $\{ \ x \ | \ \phi (x) \geq \alpha  \}$ is closed. Apparently, assuming that lack of replies implies the soundness of the proof, it was OK.

Due to the fact that, as pointed out in that question, the result is rather important, and I find on my side a certain lack of feeling for metric arguments, I was looking for another proof which focused on the sequential characterization of closed set. Again, I would like to know if this is correct.

*[Mind that, in the book I am self-studying, the question associated with this proposition comes before the standard characterization of continuity in terms of preimages of open/closed sets, hence the result can be established by pure metric arguments, and this is what I was looking for (the other – we could say – have a certain topological flavour)]*

Thus, here there is the proposed "proof".

> **Proposition:** Let $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ be a continuous function. Then, the set $\{ x \ | \ \phi (x) \leq \alpha \}$ is closed.
>
> *Proof:*
> Fix an arbitrary $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Set $\bar{A}:= \{ x \ | \ \phi (x) \leq \alpha \}$. Let $(x_m) \subseteq \bar{A}$ be an arbitrary sequence. Assume by way of contradiction that if $(x_m) \to x$, then $x \notin \bar{A}$. From the fact that $\phi$ is continous, and by using the definition of continuity based on convergence, we have that $\phi (x_m) \to \phi (x)$. Then, notice that $\phi (x_m) \leq \alpha$, and, for every $Y \subseteq X$, if $\phi (Y) \leq \alpha$, then $\phi (Y)$ is closed. Thus, $\phi (x) \leq \alpha$. But then, $x \in \bar{A}$, by definition of $\bar{A}$, establishing the desired contradiction. $\square$

As in the previous question, is this "proof" correct?
Do you have any feedbacks concerning the structure or the writing?

As always, I am really looking forward to any feedback.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: This seems fine. By the way your other proof is still not coherent e.g. you write $z \in X$ but afterwards your neighborhood definition implies $z \in \mathbb R$ and also implies $\phi(z) \in X$..

Comment: Shame on me, and really thanks a lot for this feedback (and the one on this proof)! Now I corrected the typo in the other proof. *Is it now sound afterall (I mean with the correction)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof isn't wrong, but (in my opinion) it uses proof by contradiction unnecessarily and I'm not sure about "$\phi(Y) \le \alpha$".

Just argue directly. If $(x_m) \subseteq A$ (what is the point of the overline?) is a convergent sequence with limit $x$, the continuity of $\phi$ implies $\phi(x_m) \to \phi(x)$. By an elementary order property of limits, $\phi(x_m) \le \alpha$ for all $m$ and $\phi(x_m) \to \phi(x)$ implies $\phi(x) \le \alpha$ too. Thus $x \in A$ so that $A$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, and the alternative approach! Actually, the point $\phi (Y) \leq \alpha$ was making me wonder as well, but just in the sense that it should be written as a lemma, but still it seemed to me a bit of an overshooting. Indeed, this should be an obvious result given that $\phi$ is continuous (right?).

Comment: If $y \in X$ then $\phi(y) \le \alpha$ makes sense, but if $Y \subseteq X$ you would need to clarify what $\phi(Y) \le \alpha$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: Very right, but did I not use the same notion/notation (implicitly) when I wrote $\phi (x_m) \leq \alpha$? In that case as well, $\phi (x_m)$ is a subset.

Comment: Actually, no, $\phi(x_m)$ is an element of the range.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see what you mean. Namely that $\phi (x_m)$ stands for all of the elements in the sequence, but still for all those elements taken singularly, while I did not defined explicitly $\phi (Y)$ as an object. Actually, I did not defined it – retrospectively – because when we take the metric definition of continuity and we have, given a function $f$, $f (N_\delta (x)) \subseteq N_\varepsilon (f(x))$, we are actually doing the same on the RHS, hence in some way this is already defined. [Of course, please, correct me if I am wrong!... :) ]