# Proof that in a metric space $X$, if $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ is not continuous, then $\{ x \ | \ \phi(x) \geq \alpha \}$ is not necessarily closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

In the last few days I already posted two alternative proofs ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455348/proof-that-if-phi-in-mathbbrx-is-continuous-then-x-mid-phix-ge) and the other available link) of the basic result in metric spaces that, given a continuous function $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$, the set $\{ x \ | \ \phi(x) \geq \alpha \}$ is closed for **any** $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. As explained there, I am doing the following because I realized my grasp of metric spaces and continuity arguments there is really not as it should be.

In the book I am studying, I found as a natural extension of that proposition the following point:
***the continuity of $\phi$ is necessary for the proposition to hold.***

Hence, here there is the "proof" I came up with. *I am particularly interested about feedback concerning it, because I framed it as an existential proof, and this is another topic I am really (really!) bad at, both in terms of intuition and writing skills.*

Of course, it would be nice to know overall if – beyond the proof itself – the strategy behind this specific proof is correct, or basically it is just all wrong.

Concerning the **notation**, $\delta (\varepsilon, x)$, for an arbitrary $x \in X$ denotes a $\delta$ that can possibly depend on $\varepsilon$ and $x$, while $N_{\varepsilon, X} (x)$ denotes the $\varepsilon$-nhood of $x \in X$.

> **Proposition:** In an arbitrary metric space $X$, if the function $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ is not continuous, then the set $\{ x \ | \ \phi(x) \geq \alpha \}$ is not necessarily closed.
>
> *Proof:*
> We prove that the set $G:= \{ x \ | \ \phi(x) < \alpha \}$ is not open. Hence, we have to show that there is a $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and a $\bar{x} \in G$ such that, for all $\bar{\delta} >0$, there is a $w \in N_{\bar{\delta}, X} (\bar{x})$ such that $w \notin G$.
> Let $\bar{\delta} >0$ be arbitrary. By assumption, $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ is not continuous, hence there is a $z^* \in X$ and a $\varepsilon^* > 0$ such that for every $\delta (\varepsilon^*, z^*) >0$ there is a $y \in \phi (N_{ \delta, X} (z^*))$ such that $y \notin N_{\varepsilon^*, \mathbb{R}} (\phi (z^*))$. This is equivalent to write that there is a $t \in N_{ \delta, X} (z^*)$ such that $t \notin \phi^{-1} ( N_{\varepsilon^*, \mathbb{R}} (\phi (z^*)) )$.
> By setting $\delta ( \varepsilon^*, z^*)=\bar{\delta}$, $\alpha = \phi (z^*) + 2\varepsilon^*$, $\bar{x} = z^*$, and $w = t$ the result follows. $\square$

I am really looking forward to any feedback concerning this proof, because I have some points that still leave me a bit insecure.

As always thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you might be confused. We want to show that if $\phi$ is not continuous then $\{ x : \phi(x) \ge \alpha \}$ may not be cosed. So, try to come up with a specific example. Also, I don't see why you want to show that $G$ is not open.

Comment: Um, if ϕ is not continuous than there is no stipulation of what ϕ(x) "should" be.  {x:ϕ(x)≥α} could be any darned set you want at all.  There's nothing to prove.

Comment: @Reveillark First of all, thanks a lot. Concerning the second point, this was a really bad typo that I corrected (now it should make sense). Regarding the first point, that was my first thought, and indeed I came up with a counterexample that based on $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ and on the indicator function. However, in the last few hours I thought a bit more about it, and it seemed to me that this was not really the point of the exercise, but rather that I had to look for a general proof of the fact that I tried to prove here.

Comment: There are many such discontinuous functions with the property that all such sets are closed. For example, the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $f(x) = x$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for $x\geq 0$ has $f^{-1}([\alpha,\infty))$ closed for all $\alpha \in\mathbb R$, but the function is not continuous. The point is that "not necessarily" means "there exists a counterexample", but it doesn't mean "every discontinuous function has a counterexample".

Comment: @MPW but I think according my answer there is $\alpha$ that $f^{-1}[\alpha, \infty)$ isnot closed, May i ask see it and give a hint where its pro is.

Comment: Which is also the point of my "proof" (still, if it is correct after all). Indeed I saw the logical structure of the proposition in the following way. If $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ is not continuous, then there is an $\alpha$ such that the set $G$ is not open. The point is that the negation concerning the continuity of $\phi$ does not touch the fact that $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^X$ with $X$ an arbitrary metric space.

Comment: @Kolmin what does $\delta(\epsilon^*, z^*) >0$ mean? where $\epsilon^*$ is a real number and $z^* \in X$?

Comment: oh, I got. it was better to say there is a $\alpha$ such that  $\{ x \ | \ \phi(x) \geq \alpha \}$ or  $\{ x \ | \ \phi(x) \leq \alpha \}$ isnot colsed

Comment: @Xiao: I edited the post. There are now few lines before the "proof" where I explain the notation. Sorry if it was not there before!

Comment: You don't know that $\phi(t)$ is less than $\phi(z)\$ - $\epsilon$.  It could by greater than $\phi(z)\$ + $\epsilon$.

Comment: @fleablood: Sorry for this very late answer. I think I messed up the signs. Now the definition of $\alpha$ should make everything work (right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your proof, you set $\alpha = \phi(\bar{z}) - \epsilon$, $x^*=\bar{z}$, but $x^* \not\in G : = \{ \phi(x) < \phi(\bar{z}) - \epsilon\}$.

**Edit:** I believe you want to set $\alpha = \phi(z) + \epsilon$, that way at least
$z=x\in G$ and for each $B_\delta(x)$, there exists $t\in B_\delta(x)$ such that $$\phi(t) \not\in (\phi(z) - \epsilon, \phi(z) + \epsilon)$$
However, we can not say $t\not\in G$ since we still can have $\phi(t) <\phi(z) - \epsilon$, and have $t\in G$.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I want to prove.

Comment: To show $G$ is not open, you need find $x\in G$ such that for each open ball centered at $x$, there exists a $w$ in the open ball and $w\not\in G$, can you explain more about this part.

Comment: Indeed, there was a crucial missing part (as always, my fault). Namely that we have to put $w = t$ and then it should work (if the structure is overall fine).

Comment: How can you conclude $t \not \in G$, that is $\phi(t) \not < \phi(z) -\epsilon$? And again, you need $x\in G$ and find $w\in \text{Ball}(x)$ $w\not\in G$, but here $x\not\in G$.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer, but I was digesting what you wrote. Now, I changed the sign in the definition of $\alpha$. This should make the job (I think I messed up – as always – some things).

Comment: @Kolmin but you do not have $t\not\in G$, see my answer.

Comment: First of all, let me thank you for the time you are spending on this question, who has forced me to literally see what's going on. Said so, still I think that as it is now, the proof should work. The point is that, by defining $\alpha := \phi (z^*) + 2\varepsilon$, and by the fact that $t \notin \phi^{-1} ( N_{\varepsilon^*} ( \phi (z^*)))$, the result that $\phi (t) \geq \phi (z) + 2\varepsilon$ (which is what we actually want to prove) follows *a fortiori*.

Comment: @Kolmin No problem. But you do not have $\phi(t) \geq \phi(z)+ 2\epsilon$ from $t\not\in \phi^{-1}(N_\epsilon (\phi(z)))$.

Comment: Shame on me, I finally see what you mean. Now the question is, can the structure of this proof be used to prove the result with some stretch, or is this basically doomed to failure no matter what?

Comment: @Kolmin Glad to help. First, you have to see that you are trying to prove something that is stronger than what the proposition is stating. But of course if we add other assumptions (other than the assumption $\phi$ is not continuous ), your proof will hold.

Comment: For me, the nice thing of this question and attempted proof (and your answer) is that it is the first time I face a proposition that cannot be prove with any technique you can think about. The proof should really be based on the definition of sequential convergence in closed sets as Razieh Noori did (even if I did not look at her proof because I still want to come up with it by myself).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is not continuous, then there is $x_0\in X$ and a sequence $x_n\in X$ such that $x_n\to x_0$, but $|f(x_n)-f(x_0)|>\varepsilon>0,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Without loss of generality, let $f(x_n)\geq f(x_0)$,for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$(else we could work with a subsequence or work with $\leq \alpha$). let $\alpha=f(x_0)+\varepsilon/2$, the set $B=\{x\in X:f(x)\geq\alpha\}$ is not closed, since $(x_n)_n\subseteq B$, but $x_0\notin B$.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your proof! But actually, the point of my question is to find out if my proof does make sense or not. But I do appreciate your answer.

Comment: We know that all the f(x_n) are more than epsilon away from f(x_0) but we don't know whether they are are greater than f(x_0) + epsilon, or less than f(x_0) - epsilon.  I don't see how you have prove x_n are in B. (oh, subsequences.... never mind.)

Comment: Also nitpicky, Shouldn't we restate the proposition to allow for either <= or >= and not just strictly >=?

Comment: @fleablood. please see comments.

Answer (score 0):

Let A be any set that isn't closed.  Define $\phi$(x) = $\alpha$  if x is in A; =  $\alpha$ - 1 is x is not in A.  Then $\{ x \ | \ \phi(x) \geq \alpha \}$ = A which is not closed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Still, as pointed out in a comment in a previous answer, the feedback I am looking forward concern my "proof" (if that's a proof after all) or the content of the proposition itself.

Comment: Okay, your proof is fine.   But it seems like a waste of effort for a proposition that has no informational value and is trivial to counter.  A non-continuous function can be *anything* so we can define its image to anything we want, To speculate anything about the set of domain values that map to any particular property seems pointless as we can set the function to do anything whatsoever.

Comment: Ah!  I get what you are saying.  But you should reword your proposition from its useless form to the *MUCH* stronger "for any discontinuous function you can find an alpha such that the set is not closed".  That's much stronger and contains a *LOT* more information.  I'll have to go over your proof to make sure it's right, because *THAT* is a significant result.

Comment: Thanks again! By editing the question, I tried to make more explicit the exercise I found in the book and how I read it (which should end up in the result I think I proved).

Comment: Actually, I also added a revealing line in the first paragraph ("... for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}")$ that, by not being there before, was most probably the reason behind the misunderstanding. My fault, sorry!

Comment: Just for completeness, thanks to another user I spotted a crucial last point, that I now added in the very last line and that should establish the result, namely that we have to set $w = t$.