# Basic question on the behavior of $\varepsilon$ in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Just a very easy question that is making me wonder. Mind that, as a self-learner, even if this sound silly, I never really got an answer on this.

When we use $\varepsilon >0$ and we multiply or divide it, do we actually treat it (implicitly) as a positive integer or as an arbitrary real number such that $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$?

*[I think that my confusion comes with the fact that $\varepsilon >0$ is usually presented as an arbitrary* ***small*** *real number that can be as close as you wish to $0$!]*

In other words, does $\varepsilon/2$ makes the quantity ***smaller*** or ***bigger***?

Any feedback is welcome.
Thank you for your time.

*PS: This is in some way related to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458677/proof-that-in-a-metric-space-x-if-phi-in-mathbbrx-is-not-continuous) of mine, where I use this at the end of the proof and I was really wondering about what I should really write down.*

Comment: For any positive real, $2 \epsilon > \epsilon$. As for writing $N_\epsilon(x) < \alpha$, your notation is confusing. What does it mean for an open set in a metric space to be less than a real number? 

A possible answer may be that $ N_\epsilon(x) \subset N_\alpha(x)$ for $\alpha > \epsilon$.

Comment: It is a little difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat: Ok, then – in one line – is $2\varepsilon$ a ***bigger*** or a ***smaller*** quantity than $\varepsilon$?

Comment: If $\epsilon>0$, then you must have $2 \epsilon > \epsilon$ (just add $\epsilon$ to both sides).

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks a lot!

Comment: @copper.hat: Still, let me point out that if you divide $\varepsilon$, things change: set $\varepsilon := 3$, then $\varepsilon /3= 1$ and it decreases. But if $\varepsilon := 2/3$, then $\varepsilon / 3$ increases. So with division the behavior is different. You see why I was talking about looking it in different ways. Actually the choice of $2\varepsilon$ as the main point of the question was really bad on my side!

Comment: $3 \cdot 3 = 9$.

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant $\varepsilon/3$ also when $\varepsilon := 3$. :)

Comment: @copper.hat: Btw, after some thoughts, forgive all this brainless question (I am quite ashamed of myself). I am afraid that lack of sleep is not a sufficient justification for this amazing sequence of idiotic statements I came up with.

Comment: Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you say is that $\varepsilon > 0$, then you don't necessarily have that $\varepsilon$ is an integer (since most real numbers greater than $0$ are not integers), and you also do not know that $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$.

Regarding your second question: $2\varepsilon$ is bigger than $\varepsilon$ no matter what $\varepsilon$ is, as long as it's positive.

The reason one usually thinks about $\varepsilon$ as a small number is that in analysis, we often want to prove that "something is true for all $\varepsilon > 0$", and depending a bit on what that "something" is, it's usually the case that the smaller $\varepsilon$ is, the harder it is to prove what you want. Conversely, when you have proved this "something" and want to actually apply it, then the smaller $\varepsilon$ is, the more powerful a result you get out of it.

Here's a simple example: Say we want to show that $1/n \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$. That is, we want to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N$ so that $1/n < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$.

Now say that we start by showing this for $\varepsilon = 60$. Can we find an $N$ so that $1/n < 60$ for all $n > N$? Yeah, that's completely trivial. Any natural $N$ will do the job.

On the other hand, if $\varepsilon$ had been really small, say $\varepsilon = 1/2^{60}$, then we actually need to think a little bit to cook up the necessary $N$. (Well, not that much, but hopefully you see the point.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually these two questions are really one question, namely if $2\varepsilon$ is bigger or smaller than $\varepsilon$ (the first question was a way to make it more precise, even if I am afraid it made it just more confusing).

Comment: Let's try two wildly different examples again. If $\varepsilon = 60$, then $2\varepsilon = 120$, which is bigger than $60$. On the other hand, if $\varepsilon = 1/60$, i.e. pretty small, then $2\varepsilon = 2/60 = 1/30$, which is bigger than $1/60$. No matter what $\varepsilon > 0$ is, $2\varepsilon$ will be bigger.

Comment: But if you divide it, things change: set $\varepsilon := 3$, then $ \varepsilon /3= 1$ and it decreases. But if $\varepsilon := 2/3$, then $\varepsilon / 3$ increases. So with division the behavior is different. You see why I was talking about looking it in different ways. Actually the choice of $2\varepsilon$ as the main point of the question was really bad!

Comment: There was a pedestrial typo in my previous comment that I corrected.

Comment: Btw, after some thoughts, forgive all this brainless question (I am quite ashamed of myself).